# Build error when trying to include some libraries in CDT Eclipse Luna

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, avr-gcc

Hello I'm still a newbie in using CDT in Eclipse. I was trying to include some libraries in my project.  I've tried to include header file in the GCC compiler -> Directories -> Path and Symbol but still having some error. Any answer will be helpful. Thanks.